# bondcpp fails on osx

Tags: ros, homebrew, mavericks, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I tried the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source and I know there is a section there for `bondcpp` fails and the exact problem I have, which is:

```
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
Linking CXX shared library /Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/bondcpp/lib/libbondcpp.dylib
ld: library not found for -luuid
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/bondcpp/lib/libbondcpp.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bondcpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'bondcpp':
  Command '/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/bondcpp && /Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

However the solution doesn't work. Am I doing it right?

I did:

```
brew update
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

and then tried again

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

and had no better luck.

I thank you all for the patience and time in advance.

EDIT: Output from VERBOSE=1, I ran only cd /Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/bondcpp && VERBOSE=1 /Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/1b6390b5d66046f40e5c4bd68663af64

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194158/bondcpp-fails-on-osx/) by [Tiberius](https://answers.ros.org/users/20385/tiberius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to link against `uuid`, I'm guessing we are using `pkg-config`:

```
% pkg-config --libs uuid
-L/usr/local/Cellar/uuid/1.6.2/lib -luuid
```

This looks like a bug in `bondcpp`, from your c++ command (I expanded it for easier reading), you can see that only `-luuid` is passed but the corresponding `-L/usr/local/Cellar/uuid/1.6.2/lib` is missing, that is why it cannot find the library:

```
/usr/bin/c++

-O3
-DNDEBUG
-isysroot
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
-dynamiclib
-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names


-o
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/bondcpp/lib/libbondcpp.dylib
-install_name
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/bondcpp/lib/libbondcpp.dylib
CMakeFiles/bondcpp.dir/src/timeout.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/bondcpp.dir/src/bond.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/bondcpp.dir/src/BondSM_sm.cpp.o
-luuid
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libroscpp.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/librosconsole.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.dylib
/usr/local/lib/liblog4cxx.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libroscpp_serialization.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/librostime.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libxmlrpcpp.dylib
/Users/tiberio/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libcpp_common.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libconsole_bridge.dylib
```

`bondcpp` or who ever is originally finding `uuid` is either not passing along the library directory or not converting the relative library (`-L/usr/local/Cellar/uuid/1.6.2/lib -luuid`) into an absolute library (maybe `/usr/local/Cellar/uuid/1.6.2/lib/libuuid.dylib`).

Please file an issue against `bond_core` on GitHub:

https://github.com/ros/bond_core/issues

And include as much detail from this Q&A as appropriate.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0